# view not updating when scope changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angular directive with a method that changes the scope in order to show/hide various elements with ng-show. Some of the scope properties are rendering and some are not, which is very strange.

Directive:

```
.directive('ktTable', function(Query) {
  return {
    restrict: "AC",
    templateUrl: '/partials/table.html',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {

      scope.openForm = function(options, object) {
        ...
        else if (options.checkin) {
          scope.isDocument = true;
          scope.new_object_type = "Document";
          scope.isNew = false;
          scope.isCheckin = true;
        }
        ...
      };
      scope.$watch('isNew', function(nv, ov) {
        console.log("isNew", nv, ov);
      });
      scope.$watch('isCheckin', function(nv, ov) {
        console.log("isCheckin", nv, ov);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Template:

```
<fieldset class="newFile" ng-show="isNew || isCheckin">
    <legend>New {{new_object_type}}</legend>
    <input type="file" name="newFile" />
</fieldset>
    ...
<legend><span ng-show="isNew">New </span>{{new_object_type}} Information</legend>
```

When I refresh the page, the $watch output is undefined, undefined, which is fine. The forms aren't in view anyway. When I call this method from ng-click the console output is:

```
isNew false undefined directives.js:138
isCheckin true undefined directives.js:141
```

Which is exactly what I'm looking for, but the template is not updated. Calling scope.$apply() wrapping these changes or calling scope.$apply() after the changes doesn't seem to do anything to it. If I initialize the $scope.isNew property in the controller to true, I see the fieldset and the scope.new_object_type property is set correctly. However, the scope.isNew/isCheckin properties never seem to affect the template. What should I do?

Comment: Can you post a minimal plunker or fiddle?

Comment: This is probably a scope issue -- add `{{isNew}}` to your template somewhere to see if the value you expect is what the template's scope can see.  Where is kt-table being used?  Are there other directives defined on the same element?

Comment: @MarkRajcok when I do `{{isNew}}` and `{{isCheckin}}` in the template, the values are good. But the ng-show doesn't seem to be updated

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller I'm working on the fiddle, but I can't seem to get it working (I've never tried Angular with jsfiddle)

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WuXqv/7/) it works here, so I'm not sure what my problem could be